# Facebook App Insights don't reflect changes at likes and comments

Tags: php, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-insights

I'm trying to develop a Facebook App that works using Unity3D as front-end but using a PHP Web server to do the Facebook request saving the private key there.

I tested various things like uploading photos and comments an then it get reflected the new App Insigths of the App as Stories Published.

The thing I can't achieve is to see the Likes and Comments of those Stories, it remains 0.

¿There is something that I don't understand about the Likes/Comments there, or I'm doing something bad?

Thank you all.

P.D: Sorry about my English ^^'

**Edit:**

I can't provide example code of what i've done but I can explain it.

Actually my front-end do get requests to a backend PHP server that do the requests to Facebook.

When a user want to log in the server return the login url in a string and the front-end launches a Internet navigator (in my case is Google Chrome).

The callback url given to Facebook go to a site that closes automatically the navigator and putting in first plane my front-end.

From there you can do the request to the back-end to publish stories in Facebook and then log-out

Actually this is what my application do and it works. The only problem is that the comments and likes that those stories got are not reflected in the App Insights section.

Comment: Please can you provide some examples regarding what you have tested and the errors / results you are getting.